# In Ipython, I can't use %run command. " File not found"

Tags: ipython

As you know. I'm studying first page of ipython. ( Specific title is "Python for data analysis")

If you help me about this, I will buy you dinner when you come to my country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But still "File not found" error generally occurs when you are not giving the correct file path or file name.
My suggestion is to put the file in the same directory of your python home and then try to run it. (Hope you have created the file).

Be more specific when you ask a question.

Comment: I know your suggestion. but where? I don't know where I have to put the file.  I can see this [ERROR : File 'u'abc.py' not found.]  and I put the files in this path [C:\python27\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Lib\site-packages\IPython\lib]

Comment: [Code Editor, Python Shell, and File Browser](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html) this might help you.

Comment: It's not looking in the IPython installation folder, it's looking in your working directory. Run `%pwd` inside IPython to see where that is.

Comment: Thank you! SudodhD and Thomas K! I have solved the proplem by using %pwd!

Comment: @Dongingang If you are satisfied with the answer then please accept it.. :)